# How do I initialize an attribute of a super class from an instance of its subclass? I have more questions

Tags: c#, oop

**super class student**

```
namespace StudentPresentationGUI
{
    public class Student
    {
        public string name;
    }
}
```

**sub class UnderGraduate**

```
namespace StudentPresentationGUI
{
public class UnderGraduate : Student
{
    private string classification;
    private string guardianname;
    private string address;

    public UnderGraduate(string classif, string guardian, string addr)
    {
        classification = classif;
        guardianname = guardian;
        address = addr;
    }

    UnderGraduate()
    {

    }

    protected string getClassification()
    {
        return classification;
    }

    protected string getGuardianName()
    {
        return guardianname;
    }

    protected string getAddress()
    {
        return address;
    }

}}
```

Lets say I instantiate Student:

```
Student stud1 = new UnderGraduate("Senior", "mom", "New York");
```

**Questions:**

1. How do I use the string 'name' of the super class to put a name on the instance 'stud1'?
2. What is the difference(advantages/disadvantages)

   ```
   Student stud1 = new UnderGraduate("Senior", "mom", "New York");
   ```

   over

   ```
   UnderGraduatestud1 = new UnderGraduate("Senior", "mom", "New York");
   ```

   over

   ```
   Student stud1 = new Student("Senior", "mom", "New York");
   ```

   What can I do with first first instantiation that i cant do on the second and third
   and vice versa.

Comment: Both your questions are just about basic polymorphism, and pose no actual programming problems. You should just read a few courses or articles on inheritance in general.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1445/Introduction-to-inheritance-polymorphism-in-C

Answer (score 0):

You would need either to (1) affect the name directly in the subclass constructor or make a constructor in your supperclass and call it from the sub class :

**Option (1) :**

```
namespace StudentPresentationGUI
{
    public class Student
    {
        public string name;
    }
}
```

/

```
namespace StudentPresentationGUI
{
public class UnderGraduate : Student
{
    private string classification;
    private string guardianname;
    private string address;

    //CHANGES HERE
    public UnderGraduate(string classif, string guardian, string addr, string _name) 
    {
        classification = classif;
        guardianname = guardian;
        address = addr;
        name = _name;
    }

    UnderGraduate()
    {

    }

    protected string getClassification()
    {
        return classification;
    }

    protected string getGuardianName()
    {
        return guardianname;
    }

    protected string getAddress()
    {
        return address;
    }

}}
```

**Option (2) :**

```
namespace StudentPresentationGUI
{
    public class Student
    {
        public string name;
    }

    //CHANGES HERE
    public Student(string _name) 
    {
        name = _name;
    }
}
```

/

```
namespace StudentPresentationGUI
{
public class UnderGraduate : Student
{
    private string classification;
    private string guardianname;
    private string address;

    //CHANGES HERE (Look to the right)
    public UnderGraduate(string classif, string guardian, string addr, string _name) : base(_name) 
    {
        classification = classif;
        guardianname = guardian;
        address = addr;
    }

    UnderGraduate()
    {

    }

    protected string getClassification()
    {
        return classification;
    }

    protected string getGuardianName()
    {
        return guardianname;
    }

    protected string getAddress()
    {
        return address;
    }

}}
```

The instruction `: base(_name)` calls the base class' (superclass) constructor and gives it `_name` as a parameter value.

**Other questions**

**Question 1 :**
Since it is public, you only have to call it as it was part of the subclass (ex `this.name = "Bob";`). If you wanted to hide it from the other classes (to respect encapsulation) and made it private, you would have no way of using it in the subclass (apart from public get and set functions). To hide it but use it in your subclass, you would need ot make it protected. This allows the subclasses to see it, while hiding it to the other classes. You would then be able to use it the same way you did when it was public.

**Question 2 :**

```
Student stud1 = new UnderGraduate("Senior", "mom", "New York");
```

This declares a variable of type `Student` and puts an object of type `UnderGraduate` in it. The advantage of this is to allow you to put objects of any subclass of `Student` (if it had more than one) in this variable (this is called "Polymorphism"). THe disadvantage is that if you want to use fields or functions specific to your subclasses (not in the superclass), you would need to cast this variable in the subclass everytime.

```
UnderGraduatestud1 = new UnderGraduate("Senior", "mom", "New York");
```

This declares a variable and instaciates an object of the same type (`UnderGrade`). The advantage is to allow you to use any specific functions and field of your subclass without casting it and the only disadvantage is not to have the advantage of the previous method.

```
Student stud1 = new Student("Senior", "mom", "New York");
```

This would not work since you are trying to instanciate an object of the `Student` class with the constructor of the `Student`, but the signature (parameters) of the `Undergrade` class. However, the `Student` class *does not* contain a definition for that constructor signature and your code would therefore not compile. You have to use either one of the two first methodsm as these are pretty much the only one in my knowledge.

I hope to have answered all of your questions, and if I did, I would grealy apreciate if you would upvote and mark my answer as correct (I am new here and I'm trying ot gain reputation).

Answer (score -1):

Generally, inheritance is done to reuse code. For example, the student class can be inherited by undergrad, postgrad, etc but the point is anything that is common to derived classes will go to the parent class.

However, there is a rule ( best practice) saying prefer Composition over inheritance ( which reduces coupling

As long as you have protected or public property in the parent , you can access it from derived classes.

The advantage of having parent class variable is that that variable can be assigned to from different instances of different derived classes.

Comment: -1 for teaching really bad practices - you should invoke the constructor chain properly and let the `Student` class initialize its own members.

Comment: Anyone else willing to help?